# Python xmltodict Force Array with attribute

Tags: python, json, xml, xmltodict

I've been using the python package xmltodict very successfully to parse my xml string into a python dictionary.

However, I have the following issue:

```
<child>
  <episode>["a","b"]</episode>
</child>
```

parses as:

```
 { 
  child: {
    episode: ["a","b"]
    }
 }
```

whereas:

```
<child>
  <episode>["a","b"]</episode>
  <episode>["c","d"]</episode>
</child`
```

parses as:

```
{ child: 
   {
    episode: [
     ["a","b"],
     ["c","d"]
     ]
    }
 }
```

which means that an code I write is going to give me different results depending on which child observation I'm looking at.

What I'd like is a way to specify to parse the episode always as an array - similarly to this [.Net package](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm). What would be the best way (or *a* way) of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

Try a flatten function on the `"episodes"` key?

```
def flatten(it):
    res = []
    for item in it:
        if not isinstance(item, list):
            res.append(item)
            continue
        res.extend(item)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

xmltodict provides [force_list](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/8c8cdd2f17520e0422dbe8cda6156e98375e02d3/xmltodict.py#L270) for this use case.

Here's how it would work:

```
>>> xmltodict.parse(xml, force_list=('episode'))
{'child': {'episode': ['["a","b"]']}}
```